# Display details on mocha + chai unit tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm using `Mocha` + `Chai` (with `ChaiAsPromised` plug-in) to test my backend `node` application.
I want to test for errors in a certain unit. I am expecting to get `undefined`, and fail on any other output.

For example:

```
  it('should fail creating without name', done => {
    var errors = models.Alias.build({
      AssociationId: faker.random.number()
    }).validate();
    expect(errors).to.eventually.not.exist.notify(done);
  })
```

If the test fails, I see this output:

`1) Models: Alias should fail creating without name:
     AssertionError: expected { Object (name, message, ...) } to not exist`

I wish to display more details about the `Object` and the failure reason. How can I tell `mocha`/`chai` to print the `Object` with its fields and content?

Comment: Have you tried logging the errors promise result ?

Comment: Yes it gives me a detailed object with the errors from `sequelize`. For example, `{..., message: AssociationId should not be null ,...}`